# How can I set Debian 9 (Dolphin file manager) to recognize .m files as Octave programs?

Tags: debian, dolphin, octave

Octave `.m` files are seen as some sort of text files in the Dolphin file manager on my Debian 9 system. They do not show the Octave icon. I'd like to be able to  open the Octave script directly by clicking on them which is currently not happening.

Answer (score 0):

**File association** ;

- Right click on one of your Octave file.
- Click on Properties, then File Type Options

  Filename Patterns should be *.m

  Leave the Description to MATLAB script/function
- In Application Preference Order

  Click Add

  If a search for octave return no result, go to Education/Mathematics

  Remove other application from the list

**Change the icon :**

- Click on the icon (at the left of Filename Patterns)

  System Icons

  Replace Mimetypes in the menu by Applications

  Search for octave and select

  Click Apply then Ok

  Quit the folder you're in (or refresh it - my default shortcut is F5)

  Return to the folder

Test if everything is ok.

Comment: The file association method you mentioned didn't seem to work, I have now set only GNU Octave as application for .m files, but I'm still unable to open them except by opening octave itself beforehand. Right-clicking and "Open with GNU Octave" also doesn't open the script.